# Is returning pair from method considered a good practice in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a complex method that doesn't get more complex when I gain two different values inside the method. They're substracted from the same lib class, but my use of them will not be connected anymore in my code.
I also don't want to have them declared as class fields.

Therefore my first idea is to return them as Pair because that means I don't need to call a very similar complex method twice. But on the other hand, it seems strange to return two unconnected values in Pair structure.

My question is more general: **Is returning a pair of two unconnected values (from my class point of view) considered a good practice?**

I am in kotlin, so if there are differences between languages, I need the answer specifically for kotlin.

Comment: Can you show us the `fun` and maybe some example code where it is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with returning a Pair.

But since Kotlin can create a simple data class in one line, it's often better to return one of those instead.  That way, the two values have descriptive names instead of just ‘first’ and ‘second’, and you don't need to remember which order they're in.  For example:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun findPerson(): Person {
    // …
    return Person(name, age)
}

fun main() {
    val person = findPerson()
    println("Name = ${person.name}, age = ${person.age}.")
}
```

(Of course, this is a contrived example, in which the returned values have an obvious relationship.  But even when they don't, an ‘XxxResult’ data class can be easier to use than a Pair.)

Comment: I find it easier to return Pair from methods that are not part of the "public API" of my application, for instance methods returning some kind of "state". Usually, in these cases, I use destructive declarations, which work with pairs/triples as well as with data classes.

Comment: @MarošŠeleng, I guess you mean destruct**uring** declarations?  :-)  Yes, they can be useful — though you need to take care to get the values in the right order, especially if there's no obvious order and/or they're not all different types.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. :D Haven't notice I was using it incorrectly

Comment: I would definitely consider my own data class if both returned values have the same type.